# Two separate arrays or a single 2D array. Which is better?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm processing a string which contains the name of people, locations, etc.
Which kind of array is better in terms of memory usage since I'm developing it in Android.

My guess is that the 2D array will take up more memory. For example: Number of people are 5 and the number of locations is 1. So if I initialized a 2D array it would be 2x5. With [0][x] for people and [1][x] for location. So that means that [1][1]-[1][4] would not be used and be null. But the system will reserve memory for those indices.

Therefore, two separate arrays are better.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For the sizes of array you are talking about, the difference is inconsequential. Use whatever makes your code most readable.

Comment: So it doesn't impact memory that much?

Comment: Don't use arrays, use classes. `public class Person { private String name; private Whatever location; }`

Comment: Use a class then U can simply use a List to iterate over and get the desired result, It will keep things simple and easy to maintain and change.

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of overtuning performance - I would rather make logical data structure. If the people and location is a one-to-one relationship, I wouldn't hesitate to use a `Map`. If the people and location aren't really related, I'd simply split them into two arrays or lists. Using 2D array probably makes the codes harder for others to understand .

Comment: @LexF It's not so much that it doesn't impact memory, it's that it is highly unlikely that this has the most significant impact on your memory. Write clear, working code first; then, and *only* if there actually is a performance problem, profile it to determine where the most impact is.

Comment: Are they two unrelated things? Also you can have `String[][] data = new String[2][];` then `data[0] = new String[4];` and `data[1] = new String[1];`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not prematurely optimise. The time you save developing and bugfixing with a data structure you can readily understand may be greater than any benefits from compact memory usage. (Erwin's comment on classes is pertinent).

That aside, the single array is more compact. Arrays have an allocation of 24 bytes, even when they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there are no "2d" arrays: there are only 1d arrays, but they can be arrays of arrays (which can be arrays of arrays of arrays, etc).

Creating a 2d array creates multiple 1d arrays to hold your elements, and then an array to hold references to those arrays. This is an object, which comes with some overhead itself, as well as array-specific things like the length.

Using separate 1d arrays means you are holding references to those arrays yourself.

So, there are slight savings by having separate arrays, because you don't have to store the gubbins needed to store that extra array.

*However*, unless you are creating vast numbers of pairs of these arrays, the difference is unlikely to be important. Stick to whatever makes for the most logical, readable code.